# Why Elasticsearch is so slow in Junit test?

Tags: java, api, rest, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use ElasticSearch so I built a simple JUnit test but the test took like 5 seconds to run which I think it's pretty slow. Not sure if I miss out anything?

```
        Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().node();
        Client client = node.client();

        BulkRequestBuilder brb = client.prepareBulk();

        Map<String, Object> json = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Object> nest = new HashMap<>();
        nest.put("foo", "blah");

        json.put("Code", "123");
        json.put("nut", nest);
        json.put("images", newArrayList("image1", "image2"));

        brb.add(new IndexRequest("promotions", "promotion").source(json));
        brb.execute().actionGet();

        MatchQueryBuilder itemNumber = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("Code", "123");
        SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch("promotions").setTypes("promotion").setQuery(itemNumber).execute().actionGet();

        assertThat((List)sr.getHits().getHits()[0].getSource().get("images")).contains("image1");
        assertThat((List)sr.getHits().getHits()[0].getSource().get("images")).contains("image2");
        assertThat((List)sr.getHits().getHits()[0].getSource().get("images")).doesNotContain("image3");
```

Comment: it builds up an es instance in memory to run the tests against, so that might be kind of slow. Have you timed the search part of the test vs. the initialization part of the test?

Comment: The search part is quite quick, but the initialization and index take quite sometime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to switch to a local node for testing. That way you disable zen discovery and only other nodes runnning in the same jvm can join the same cluster. Also, no tcp transport between nodes (if you have more than one, which doesn't seem to be the case), as they are in the same jvm. Your node will still open the http transport (9200 port by default) though, you might want to disable that if you don't need it.

And anyway, don't ever forget to set the cluster name! What your node is doing when you start the test is looking in your network if there are other nodes running with the same cluster name. If that's the case it will join the existing cluster and will start sharing data with those other nodes, leading to weird test behaviours.

```
Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().clusterName("my_cluster").local(true).node();
```

Comment: Strangely enough I just added my clusterName and the test failed. Not sure why that could cause my test to fail? This is what I do.         Node node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().clusterName("Andreas von Strucker").local(true).node();. It's like the document wasn't indexed properly so it couldn't find the document via search api.

Comment: Not sure why this is related to changing the cluster name, probably you were joining an already existing cluster that already contained that document? I guess the problem is that you need to call the refresh api to be able to find the new document. Otherwise you can use the get api (by id) which works in real-time.